# Remove web element from the IList <IWebElement> using C# in Selenium

Tags: c#, list, selenium

I'm actually trying to remove the element from IList if certain condition occurs, but seems like I'm getting the same list `.Count` number. Below is my code:

```
    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//button[@aria-label='delete']")]
    private IList <IWebElement> _deleteIcons;

******** SOME CODE HERE **********

    for (var i = 0; i<_deleteIcons.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (_deleteIcons[i].GetAttribute("disabled").Contains("true"))
                    {
                        _deleteIcons.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
    Debug.WriteLine(_deleteIcons.Count);
```

Imagine there are **6** total elements in the IList, and 2 of them contain `"disabled" =="true"` At the end I would like to write to debug console the variable count and see **4**.  Currently once the piece of code is run, I still get the same amount of 6 elements in IList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a CSS selector and just select those buttons that are not disabled. It will be faster and you won't need to filter afterwards.

```
"button[aria-label='delete']:not([disabled])"
```

Comment: Both approaches work, but yours seems more convenient. Accepting it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do before your for loop

```
_deleteIcons = [CODE_TO_GET_ELEMENETS].ToList()
```

Then this should work

or you can use Linq to achieve this without the need for this loop:

```
_deleteIcons = [CODE_TO_GET_ELEMENETS].Where(x => x.GetAttribute("disabled").Contains("true"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation occur where I used a LINQ query to rebuild the list I was making. [System.NotSupportedException: 'Collection is read-only.' thrown when removing object from iList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187478/system-notsupportedexception-collection-is-read-only-thrown-when-removing-ob)

I know you've had an answer already but just putting this out there too.